# Plot3D Power::infty error I do not understand

Tags: plotting, warning-messages, version-9

I am receiving Power::infty error when running the following code (and nothing is plotted).

`Plot3D[1/k, {m, 0, 1}, {k, m + 1, m + 2}]`

The k variable is in [1,3] and hence I do not understand what is happening. When I change the plotted function to *k*, I receive the expected plot, in which *k* is at least one.

Thank you

EDIT: I am even more puzzled since I added evaluation monitor.

`EvaluationMonitor :> Print[{k, m}]`

I am getting the same Power::infty error and no output of the evaluation monitor.

Comment: no problem on V 13.1. Did you try from clean kernel?  Screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4QGn.png)

Comment: @Nasser Thank you! This helps. I am on V 9.0. On the other hand, this is such a simple thing.

Comment: Weird, in Wolfram Cloud, I did see `Plot3D::plln` *"Plot3D: Limiting value1+min{k,1+m,2+m}is not a machine-sized real number"* error once, then restarted the Kernel and no more error.

Comment: @rhermans Thank you. The error is version/platform specific and elusive. This suggests something 'deeper' is going on.

Comment: Another solution is `Quiet[Plot3D[...], Power::infty]`. Another test is `ClearAll[foo]; foo[m_?NumericQ, k_?NumericQ] := (Print[{k, m}]; 1/k); Plot3D[foo[m, k], {m, 0, 1}, {k, m + 1, m + 2}]`.  `Plot3D` does some symbolic analysis before evaluating for the plot; it may be bypassing `EvaluationMonitor` at this preliminary stage. (One used to get this message in older versions, like pre-V6 or pre-V5. They changed it to suppress the message.) Yet another test is to nudge the intervals a little, like `{m, 10^-8, 1}, {k, m + 1 + 10^-9, m + 2}`, although I don't expect a difference in this case.

Comment: @Michael E2. Thank you! The `foo` trick shows that `EvaluationMonitor` is being bypassed. None of the `Quiet` and `10^-8` proposals gets rid of the `Power::infty` error. Since my original error is version/platform specific, I would close this discussion as mystery not worth solving. Thank you anyway!